# KDGKBENT returns wrong keysym values?

Tags: c, unicode, linux-kernel, keyboard, keycode

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/keyboard.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/kd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct kbentry ke;
  
  ke.kb_table = (unsigned char)atoi(argv[1]);
  ke.kb_index = (unsigned char)atoi(argv[2]);
  ioclt(0, KDGKBENT, &ke);
  printf("keycode %u = %04x\n", ke.kb_index, ke.kb_value);
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to get the value of a keycode using e.g. the code above, KDGKBENT returns strange values. It adds a '0B' to ASCII characters: 0x0B61 for 'a' instead of 0x0061, 0x0B41 for 'A' instead of 0x0041.

I cannot find any answer regarding to what this happens on the internet.

I only found the same question, without any answer there:
https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/178627-questions-about-linux-console-keyboard-driver-translation-tables.html

Those values in 0x0Bxx do not appear when running dumpkeys -l (alphabet has normal ASCII values), nor in this list:
https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_keysyms

Why does this happen? And how am I supposed to get a proper conversion?

Actually, looking carefully at dumpkeys tables, the alphabet keys symbols are '+a', '+A' etc. i.e. they are Caps Lock conditioned to change their case. Could be the explanation behind '0x0B' but I need to find a confirmation about this theory.

Comment: ke.kb_value is a short are you using the correct printf code?

Comment: JGNI: you can check the code I provided. I don't understand why you ask. Also I only get this problem with letters, not numerals nor other symbols. Which is why I believe this could be due to the '+' modifier. But I cannot find the proper documentation.